# Division modular en Python

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles

Estoy haciendo una función donde defino que el tamaño del bloque es de 4096kb y usando la division modular tengo que saber cuál sería el tamaño del bloque que usaría un archivo de x tamaño. por ejemplo si el archivo fuera de 4096kb se ocuparía un bloque de 4096kb y si el archivo pesara 4097kb ya se estaría utilizando un bloque de  8192kb. Por otro lado, si el archivo pesara 1kb tambíen se usaria un bloque de 4096kb. Aquí mi codigo

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize//block_size
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = ___
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return ___
    return ___

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No me gustan los `if` ni las condiciones:

```
block_size = 4096
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    return block_size * ((filesize + block_size - 1) // block_size)
```

El truco estándar es sumar el tamaño del bloque menos una posición al tamaño del archivo antes de la división. Así podemos hacer la división sin preocuparnos del resto que pueda quedar.

**Demo**

```
print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

produce:

```
4096
4096
8192
8192
```

Answer (score 3):

Podemos razonar de la forma siguiente para hallar el número de bloques necesario:

- Si el tamaño total fuese múltiplo del tamaño del bloque, sería la división entera entre el tamaño total y el del bloque
- Si no fuese múltiplo habría que sumar un bloque más.

La división entera con Python3 se calcula con el operador `//`. Para saber si un número es múltiplo de otro podemos usar el módulo, que nos da el resto de la división. Si el módulo es 0 es que es múltiplo y si es distinto de 0 es que no lo es.

Por tanto la comparación `tam % bloque != 0` nos dice si hace falta un bloque más. Además podemos hacer uso de un truco y es que si un booleano aparece dentro de una operación aritmética, Python lo convertirá en 1 (si el booleano era `True`) o 0  (si era `False`).

Así, podemos juntar todo lo anterior en una sola fórmula:

```
numero_de_bloques = tam//bloque + (tam%bloque != 0)
```

Lo que nos lleva a una función que puede consistir en una sola línea:

```
def calculate_storage(tam, block=4096):
  return block * (tam//block + (tam%block != 0))
```

De paso he puesto `block` como parámetro, para que la función sea más general y pueda aplicarse en casos en que el tamaño del bloque sea distinto de 4096.

Answer (score 1):

talves puedas hacer uso de la funcion `divmod`

```
print('divmod(8, 3) = ', divmod(8, 3))
print('divmod(3, 8) = ', divmod(3, 8))
print('divmod(5, 5) = ', divmod(5, 5))

# divmod() with Floats
print('divmod(8.0, 3) = ', divmod(8.0, 3))
print('divmod(3, 8.0) = ', divmod(3, 8.0))
print('divmod(7.5, 2.5) = ', divmod(7.5, 2.5))
print('divmod(2.6, 0.5) = ', divmod(2.6, 0.5))


**Output**

divmod(8, 3) =  (2, 2)
divmod(3, 8) =  (0, 3)
divmod(5, 5) =  (1, 0)
divmod(8.0, 3) =  (2.0, 2.0)
divmod(3, 8.0) =  (0.0, 3.0)
divmod(7.5, 2.5) =  (3.0, 0.0)
divmod(2.6, 0.5) =  (5.0, 0.10000000000000009)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin usar *float*, se me ocurre hacer algo similar a lo que llevas. Luego para saber si el tamaño sobrepasó el bloque, se puede comprobar con un resto de división entera `%`. Si es diferente de 0 significa que hay un sobrante. Se asigna `1` a `remaining` si hay sobrante, de lo contrario `0` y se suma a los demás bloques.

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    full_blocks = filesize // block_size
    remaining = 1 if (filesize % block_size > 0) else 0
    return (full_blocks + remaining) * block_size
```